# Firebase auth is not detecting logged in user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

The problem:
I cannot access the user object with `firebase.auth().currentUser`

The situation:
Account creation and login uses [firebaseui-web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web). User is redirected to his account specific pages upon authentication.  User cookie is validated server side before each page is rendered and served to authenticated user, ensuring that the right user content is served and that no unauthorized access occurs.  However, when accessing the user profile page where I need to access the user object using javascript, I only get a null object.  Futhermore, the console logs "user is NOT signed in" and logs "null" for the user.

The question:
How can I access the user object? Am I loading something out of sequence? Is there anything else I need to check or double check?

The html page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js h-100" lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- redacted -->  
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="main-stylesheet" data-version="1.1.0" href="/static/dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dashboard/styles/extras.1.1.0.min.css">
    <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.snow.css"> 
</head>

  <body class="h-100">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- The page content goes here-->
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/shards-ui@latest/dist/js/shards.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sharrre/2.0.1/jquery.sharrre.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/dashboard/scripts/extras.1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/dashboard/scripts/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/dashboard/scripts/app/app-blog-new-post.1.1.0.js"></script>

    <!-- toastr -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>


    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "MyApiKey",
          authDomain: "MyAuthDomain",
          databaseURL: "myDatabaseURL",
          projectId: "myProjectId",
          storageBucket: "myStorageBucket",
          messagingSenderId: "myMessagingSenderId",
          appId: "myAppId"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      </script>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log("user is signed in");
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            // The user gets 
            console.log("user is NOT signed in");
          }
        });
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        console.log(user);
        //logs 'null'

        // additional code redacted
      })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a race going on. You put both firebase scripts in the body.  The second is listening for `document ready`, which may be triggering before you're connected to the `firebase.auth()`.

I would put both inside the listener, or connect via script in the `<head>`, or put them in the `<head>` under one `<script>` tag and create a read flag.

Try this (still waiting for doc ready):

```
<body>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "MyApiKey",
          authDomain: "MyAuthDomain",
          databaseURL: "myDatabaseURL",
          projectId: "myProjectId",
          storageBucket: "myStorageBucket",
          messagingSenderId: "myMessagingSenderId",
          appId: "myAppId"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log("user is signed in");
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            // The user gets 
            console.log("user is NOT signed in");
          }
        });
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        console.log(user);
        //logs 'null'

        // additional code redacted
      })
</script>
```

Or this (connect to `firebase` before writing to DOM):

```
<head>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "MyApiKey",
          authDomain: "MyAuthDomain",
          databaseURL: "myDatabaseURL",
          projectId: "myProjectId",
          storageBucket: "myStorageBucket",
          messagingSenderId: "myMessagingSenderId",
          appId: "myAppId"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log("user is signed in");
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            // The user gets 
            console.log("user is NOT signed in");
          }
        });
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        console.log(user);
        //logs 'null'

        // additional code redacted
      })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I attempted to use both solutions, however, I still wasn't able to get the user object. My guess is that I probably have a more complex issue to resolve in my code. I worked around it by simply doing server side user validation through an ajax request.  Once again, thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: If it fixes your issue, you should accept the answer for posterity.

Comment: It doesn't resolve the issue, unfortunately. I did go ahead and upvote your answer. My guess is that my problem may not have been narrowed done sufficiently yet, for it to be answered in the stack overflow format